# Conservation of energy with an increase in mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, energy-conservation, collision

I'm doing a problem about momentum which describes the squirrel from Ice Age picking up nuts as he slides through ice with no friction (author seems lighthearted lol). After picking 5 nuts, it's velocity decreases because of the increase in mass and conservation of momentum. After calculating the new velocity after that mass is added, it asks me to calculate the difference in the kinetic energy before and after adding this mass. I applied the formula and got the correct answer, $\Delta E_k=-7.5\text{ J}$. Where did this energy go? Shouldn't the energy conserve, as there is no difference in gravitational potential energy or any kind of elastic potential energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only elastic collisions conserve kinetic energy - inelastic collisions do not. Since the nuts are not bouncing off the squirrel but are instead "absorbed" as they are picked up, we can model this as a series of inelastic collisions. As the squirrel picks up the nuts, there will be some deformation as the nuts are accelerated to the squirrel's speed, resulting in some energy being lost in non-useful forms like heat or sound.

Momentum is conserved in both elastic and inelastic collisions, but kinetic energy is only conserved in elastic collisions. In an elastic collision, objects may deform, but they'll return to their original shape and bounce apart. In an inelastic collision, the collision force causes objects to deform, but they do not bounce back to their original shape - the work done in deforming the objects is not recovered in any useful form. One can imagine two cars crashing - a significant amount of work goes into bending the frame of the car and heating the metal, but you can't get that energy back "out" of the bent frame like you could with two colliding springs.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you didn't use $\frac 1 2 mv^2$ to compute the energy loss. $p^2/2m$ is much nicer, so that:

$$\Delta T=\frac 1 2 p^2\Delta(\frac 1 m)=-\frac{p^2}2 \frac{\Delta m}{m_fm_i}$$
$$=-\frac{p^2}2 \frac{5M_{nut}}{M^2_{squirrel}+5M_{squirrel}M_{nut}}$$
$$=-\frac 1 2 v_i^2\frac{5M_{nut}}{1+5\frac{M_{nut}}{M_{squirrel}}}$$

The kinetic energy is reduced because the nuts do work on the squirrel.

If he just grabbed them with a mitt, that energy would heat the mitt....not very satisfactory.

If instead, he has a nut catching massless spring, he needs to smoothly bring the nuts to rest in his frame. With that, he allows the stationary nut to compress the spring.
When the nut matches the squirrel speed, he clamps down the spring. That stores potential energy.

If he does this with all 5 nuts he has five compressed springs with potential energy equal to the lost kinetic energy.

Extra credit: if the spring constant is $k$, how far are the springs compressed? Are they all the same?